# Load a javascript file in a UIWebView

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, uiwebview, nsurl

How do I load a `UIWebView` and then request a javascript file from my server and load that into the `UIWebView`?

Say a problem occurs with the js code and I update it, you can refresh the app so that it sends a new request for the javascript file and you'll have the new version.

EDIT:

I already have the `UIWebView` and it loads a website. I know how to load js from the main bundle but I need to send a request in the UIWebViewDIdFinishLoad and grab the javascript file from my server to load in the UIWebView.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to download the js file with the Alamofire or AFNetworking. There are very simple methods to download files from the Internet. Download it save it and use them to load the web view.

[Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire)

[AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking)

**Download**

```
NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
AFURLSessionManager *manager = [[AFURLSessionManager alloc] initWithSessionConfiguration:configuration];

NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://example.com/download.zip"];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:URL];

NSURLSessionDownloadTask *downloadTask = [manager downloadTaskWithRequest:request progress:nil destination:^NSURL *(NSURL *targetPath, NSURLResponse *response) {
    NSURL *documentsDirectoryURL = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomain:NSUserDomainMask appropriateForURL:nil create:NO error:nil];
    // Save this following url to load the file
    return [documentsDirectoryURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:[response suggestedFilename]];
} completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSURL *filePath, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"File downloaded to: %@", filePath);
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setURL:filePath forKey:@"URL_TO_SAVE"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

}];
[downloadTask resume];
```

**Load To WebView**

```
NSURL *URL = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] URLForKey:@"URL_TO_SAVE"];
NSString *javaScript = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:URL encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error: nil];
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:javaScript];
```

Comment: Would you have a tutorial or sample code showing how to use AFNetworking to download, save it, and use to load the web?

Comment: Random question, does downloading the file save it to the iOS device multiple times and take up memory on the iPhone?

Comment: In this case I think the files are overwritten (I'm not sure) if you don't change the file name

Comment: If you have to concern, you have to manage the files and it is a whole new topic. You need to manually see the folder and delete what you don't need!

Comment: Alright. And this method for downloading a file and loading it into web view is accepted by Apple?

Comment: Awesome! :) The file I'm downloading is on my DreamHost server, do you think that every time you open the app and it downloads the file onto the web view it will count as server usage?

Comment: I think so. In not very familiar with the server usage but I think it sure will take up bandwidth.

Comment: Right. Because I'd have to assume if the app had 10,000 users and their all using the app and that file is being downloaded, it would have to effect something on the server side. If the app had 1,000,000 users I would imagine you'd have to get a virtual private server to keep up with the demand.

Comment: Yes you need to have those things in mind! Sir, would you let me know what the purpose of the app? It quite interesting approach keeping just JavaScript up to date.

Comment: Hi, please help me out with this. My js file is at below address:

http://IP_ADDRESS:PORT_NUMBER/front/initialize-client.js

How do I load this into UIWebView?

I tried downloading the js using AFNetworking and used stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString function as well. No luck.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hello @JasonNam is there any chance you might be able to help me get this to work again? I can't seem to download the js file and load it to my uiwebview.

Comment: Okey! So the problem is..??

Comment: @JasonNam The js file i'm trying to download isn't being downloaded and loaded to the uiwebview.

Comment: Did you NSLoged the downloaded file??